Kibana service on centos 7 server virtual machine failed to star with code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
I'm trying to setup Elasticsearch and Kibana on my local CentOS 7 virtual machine. I successfully installed ES and Kibana, elasticsearch is working and accessible at: 127.0.0.1:9200, but when the Kibana service is failed to start:
Here's my kibana configuration [ /etc/kibana/kibana.yml ]:
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]

logging:
  appenders:
    file:
      type: file
      fileName: /var/log/kibana/kibana.log
      layout:
        type: json
  root:
    appenders:
      - default
      - file

Here's what i get when run: systemctl status kibana:
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2024-08-05 01:46:45 EDT; 18min ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co
  Process: 4345 ExecStart=/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4345 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 05 01:46:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Aug 05 01:46:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Aug 05 01:46:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 05 01:46:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Aug 05 01:46:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for kibana.service
Aug 05 01:46:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
Aug 05 01:46:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Aug 05 01:46:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.

Here's what i tried:

Change the host address to my local IP and also to 127.0.0.1, localhost
Created a custom log file at /usr/share/kibana and change its ownership to kibana user and give that log file in kibana configuration

But no success, what might be wrong?
